# How to perform aggregate operations (like a Group By) on a data set in Pivotal CRM

Tags: crm, pivotal-crm

In Pivotal CRM:

I have a set of applications (lets say Job applications) which I want to create a summary info screen ('Client Form') for.

I want to have a break down of applications by regions; which are defined in another table.

How do I create a grid view of say:

**Region | Number of Applications for that region | % of Total**

And for bonus points: I just want applications for this month or year

Comment: Which CRM you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, its in the title. Pivotal CRM. I have added it to the body now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a 'read only table' (View)

Create a SQL view (well just the select statement is enough) which will give you the data you need.

Use GROUP BY  and INNER JOINS to give you the data you need to calculate the percentage etc.

In Pivotal:

- Create a read only table.
- Paste in your SQL to the field in the views tab.
- Add matching fields; including the ones pivotal normally creates when you make a table. (You need to make sure the data types in the view match what pivotal would normally use.)
- Bounce the ACC
- Create lists, Querys, Search results lists , client forms as normal

See here for more details: [Pivotal CRM Read-Only Views](http://androtheos.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/pivotal-crm-read-only-views.html)